# Publishing causes a FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel'

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm getting an error when running `dotnet publish`:

```
dotnet restore
dotnet build
dotnet publish --configuration Release  --runtime active
```

The publish is successful, but I think it's having trouble with the IISIntergration/modifying web.config part.

**Error:**

```
Configuring the following project for use with IIS: 'C:\Users\john-luke.laue\repositories\MyApp\src\MyApp\bin\Release\net461\active\publish'
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools.PublishIISCommand.Run()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools.Program.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Main>b__0()
at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

**project.json**

```js
{
"userSecretsId": "aspnet5-EspritWebMvc-20150831035846",
"version": "1.0.0-*",
"buildOptions": {
  "emitEntryPoint": true,
  "preserveCompilationContext": true,
  "warningsAsErrors": true
},
"dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "type": "build"
  },
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel": "1.0.0-rc4-003206"
},

"frameworks": {
  "net461": {}
},


"runtimeOptions": {
  "configProperties": {
    "System.GC.Server": true
  }
},


"tools": {
  "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
},

"scripts": {
  "postpublish": "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%"
},


"publishOptions": {
  "include": [
    "wwwroot",
    "web.config",
    "appsettings.json",
    "**/*.cshtml",
    "Config/*.json"
  ]
}

}
```

How I can debug or solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/209) github issue contains solution. You need to clear nuget cache and restore packages (see [this](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5458#issuecomment-221912806) comment):

1. Delete `%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages\.tools\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` and `%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`
2. Make sure your "tools" section matches this:

   ```
   "tools": {
       "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
   }
   ```
3. Re run `dotnet restore`

Comment: Thanks so much. I have my entity framework code in a separate project and it was using "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools". So I did as you said and it works now!